# Unable to render an adaptive card with Node JS

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am trying to render and actionable message using JavaScript on Node. The card payload is directly picked from https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "width": "32px",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "width": "16px",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                            "url": "https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/trello-logo.png",
                            "altText": "Trello Logo"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Trello"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "width": "auto",
                    "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "width": "12px",
                            "url": "https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/Close.png",
                            "altText": "Close"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "spacing": "large",
            "separator": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "width": "32px",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "width": "32px",
                            "style": "person",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                            "url": "https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/person_m2.png",
                            "altText": "Leo Adams Profile Picture"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "**Leo Adams added a card**"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "spacing": "none",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "text": "\"Visual design for Project A\" to \"Fabrikam\" list"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "spacing": "small",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "text": "Due date: 12/12/2017"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "spacing": "none",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true,
                            "text": "Comment: \"We need to make sure we have updated designs for our meeting on Monday.\""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "width": "32px"
                        },
                        {
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "ActionSet",
                                    "actions": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                                            "title": "Add a comment",
                                            "card": {
                                                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                                "body": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                                        "isMultiline": true,
                                                        "id": "textinputid"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ActionSet",
                                                        "spacing": "small",
                                                        "actions": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "Action.Http",
                                                                "method": "POST",
                                                                "body": "{}",
                                                                "title": "OK",
                                                                "url": "https://messagecardplaygroundfn.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpPost?code=zJaYHdG4dZdPK0GTymwYzpaCtcPAPec8fTvc2flJRvahwigYWg3p0A==&message=The comment was added successfully"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                                            "title": "Move card",
                                            "card": {
                                                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                                "body": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                                                        "placeholder": "Pick a list",
                                                        "id": "choiceinputid",
                                                        "isRequired": true,
                                                        "choices": [
                                                            {
                                                                "title": "List 1",
                                                                "value": "List 1"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "title": "List 2",
                                                                "value": "List 2"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ActionSet",
                                                        "spacing": "small",
                                                        "actions": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "Action.Http",
                                                                "method": "POST",
                                                                "body": "{{choiceinputid.value}}",
                                                                "title": "OK",
                                                                "url": "https://messagecardplaygroundfn.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpPost?code=zJaYHdG4dZdPK0GTymwYzpaCtcPAPec8fTvc2flJRvahwigYWg3p0A==&message=The card was moved to '{{choiceinputid.value}}' successfully"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the sample code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/render-a-card.

The output that I get is:

```
<div class="ac-container ac-adaptiveCard" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; box-sizing: border-box; flex: 0 0 auto; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" tabindex="0"><div class="ac-container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; box-sizing: border-box; flex: 0 0 auto; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></div></div>
```

which just renders an empty body.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Do we have a sample working code that I can take inspiration from?

Many thanks in advance for helping out me here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I was receiving the definition into my method as a string, and I had to convert that into a proper Javascript object using JSON.parse(). Once I did that, it worked as expected.